# Matlab Integration of exponential function

Tags: numerical-integration

```
clear all
clc
syms x;
A=(x^3)/(exp(x)-1);
B=int(A,0,1)
```

When I run this code then it shows an expression like below

B =

log(1 - exp(1)) + 3*polylog(2, exp(1)) - 6*polylog(3, exp(1)) + 6*polylog(4, exp(1)) - limit(x^3*log(1 - exp(x)) + 6*polylog(4, exp(x)) + 3*x^2*polylog(2, exp(x)) - x^4/4 - 6*x*polylog(3, exp(x)), x == 0, Right) - 1/4

What is the polylog in the expression. But, i need one definite value, Is there any way to solve this issue so that i get a value. please anyone help me......

Comment: why are you using syms?  and int?  they returns symbolic results, not numeric.  numerical results use something like trapz for simplified symbolic use power series.

Comment: @G Alexander sorry but trapz is also not working. It is showing a result of NaN. Not a number. Pls guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
X = eps:0.01:1;
Y = (X.^3)./(exp(X)-1.0);
Z = trapz(X,Y);
```

Comment: @ G Alexander thanks fr ur reply and your code. But again if i run the code then the output is showing as'NaN' .

Comment: Ah, ok your integral is not defined around  X=0.  You need to reduce the equation to another form. Or you need a different integration technique or do something like  `X = eps:0.01:1;` where eps is the numerical limit of your machine.  You should get something like ans =  0.22481

Comment: @ G Alexander thank you very much for ur help nd fr sharing your knowledge wid me.again thanks a lot.